# Defining Range using Ranges Generated from the .Find Method

Tags: vba, find, range

I have a worksheet that has multiple rows with duplicate string data that are all sorted so they are adjacent.  I'm trying to make some VBA that can define the ranges of each block of matching string data based on a column on a worksheet I called "Index".  So far this is what I have.

```
Sub find_string_criteria_range()

Dim find_value As String
Dim start_range As Range
Dim stop_range As Range
Dim var_range As Range
Dim range_count As Integer

range_count = Worksheets("Index").Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

    For x = 2 To range_count

        find_value = Worksheets("index").Cells(x, 2).Value

        Set start_range = Worksheets("SAS DATA").Range("A:A").Find(find_value, searchdirection:=xlNext, lookat:=xlWhole)
        Set stop_range = Worksheets("SAS DATA").Range("A:A").Find(find_value, searchdirection:=xlPrevious, lookat:=xlWhole)
        var_range = Worksheets("SAS DATA").Range("start_range:stop_range")

    Next x

End Sub
```

I'm getting an "application defined or object defined error" error when I run the third to last line of code, which attempts to set var_range equal to the combined start_range and stop_range ranges.

I'm not sure how I can get the two .Find outputs to become a single range.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `.Range(start_range, stop_range)`. As written in your post VBA is looking for the literal string `start_range:stop_range`. The way I provided will ensure the named variables are used.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  When I make that change I get the Runtime error 91 'object variable or with block variable not set.'  I'm looking into why I would be getting that error now.

Comment: It might be because one of those ranges was not set (i.e. Find didn't return any range). You can check it with `If start_range Is Nothing Then`... It is advisable to set both ranges to `Nothing` before doing `.Find()`

Comment: @Logan Reed.  That is a good point.  The ranges appear to be set.  I ran the code you advised as well as running a simple `stop_range.Select` and both indicate that the ranges are being set by `.Find` So I'm still trying to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Just noticed - you should also do `Set var_range = ...`, not `var_range = ...`.

Comment: @LoganReed well, that's embarrasing.  Works fine now.  Thanks for finding that.  I'm in no way an experienced programmer but tyring to get there.  Thank you.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for - happens to me to this day. Enjoy!